# Should I register ports I use in the drivers\etc\services file?

Tags: windows, services, port

I am working on a Windows service that uses ports to discuss with client applications.

I have seen that the ports used by Windows are registered in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services` file, as well as ports used by some applications not developed by Windows.

Should I append the ports my service use in that file? Is it in anyway useful, or just informational?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is mostly just a copy of `/etc/services` from an old version of BSD – since Windows uses the same "BSD sockets" API and even brought in various client programs (*ftp*, *telnet*, *rsh*, *finger* commands) from it, it needs an `services` file in order for the `getservbyname()` function to work.

On Unix, various Internet servers and clients used to call `getservbyname()` to find out what port they should listen to; `getservbyname("finger", "tcp")` would return port 79. But when `/etc/hosts` was replaced by DNS, `/etc/services` was not – so it would quickly get out of date as the number of sites grew.

I'm guessing it's because of this that programs stopped using `getservbyname()` and started using their own config files, or hardcoded port numbers, instead. I think only the *inetd* daemon (and its *xinetd* successor) still uses service names as part of its configuration. And only legacy clients like *telnet* or *ftp* use the service names to connect.

These days, the file is mostly informational – for example, the `netstat` program can translate ports to service names, just like it translates IP addresses to hostnames.

```
$ netstat -lt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:pulse-native          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:mpd                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pulse-native       [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:netbios-ssn        [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:finger             [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:auth               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

On Windows, I'm sure, the file is used even less – I can't remember any program that uses it, other than the same *ftp* and *telnet* tools.

Comment: SAP NetWeaver RFC C++ SDK uses services file for reading its spagw ports associated to SAP instances.